# R - Merge Two member lists of a list

Tags: r, list, merge

I have list `l` of the form say :

```
R> l
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4
```

Now, I want to merge to member lists of this list. For instance, when I say I want to merge l[[1]] and l[[2]], I want the result to be :

```
R> l
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 4
```

While merging two list, I don't need dupilcate elements in the result. Hence, I am using `union` over two member lists.

```
R> union(l[[1]], l,[[2]])
[1] 1 2
```

How can I do this merge operation? Can I do this using some predefined function?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write you own merge as follows:

```
l <- as.list(1:4)

mymerge <- function(mylist, element1, element2){
  mylist[[element1]] <- union(mylist[[element1]], mylist[[element2]])
  mylist[[element2]] <- NULL
  return(mylist)
}

l <- mymerge(l,1,2)
```

Result:

```
> l
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 4
```

Comment: As akrun pointed out, you can also use `c` instead of `union`

Comment: After looking at akrun first solution, I was using `append(list(union(l[[element1]], l[[element2]])), l[-c(element1, element2)])`. But this is just what I wanted. Thanks.